# Hot Network Questions (temporarily) gone?

Tags: support, hot-questions-list

I notice recently that the right side of pages (both the main page and question pages) shows a list of tags and recent badges instead of a list of Hot Network Questions that usually appears. The [hot questions list](https://stackexchange.com/questions) can still be accessed via its usual webpage.

I also noticed [this uber Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298151/287661) saying there would be scheduled maintenance that seems to be going on at the moment.

Question 1a) Is everyone missing the HNQs? (A browsing of the Hot-Questions tag at uber Meta didn't reveal anything relevant)

Question 1b) If so, is this maintenance-related?

EDIT: Two hours later, they're back.

Comment: I also got a DNS error or two; I'm imagining it's not all a coincidence...

Comment: I got such a message seven to eight hours ago.  I know there was some maintenance notice for today, can't remember when, though.

Comment: As far as "Hot Network Questions", I'd be delighted to have them permanently removed from any list of them shown on the right; for those who follow them, they have the link to the relevant web-page you've given.